# In mySQL how does AddwithValue() handle variable types width C#

Tags: c#, mysql, variables

I wonder how does `AddwithValue()` in mySQL
Handles variables, width commands like INSERT, should i put in text valeus matching exactly a value kind in mysql. 
To input a number in a table:
should i use myvalue="123.33"
or
myvalue = (double)123.33333333
myvaleu = (decimal)123.333

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString;
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO temperature(sample1,sample2) VALUES(@sample1, @sample2)";
comm.Parameters.Add("@sample1", "123.33");
double sample2 = 123.0 + 1/3;
comm.Parameters.Add("@sample2", sample2);   //is that ok?
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

I'm wondering this because, often its configured in mySQL how many decimals a variable has.

Currentl my C# application reads:
Doubles
Decimals
Dates (full date+time)

Comment: adjusted question, indeed it wasnt that clear

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use AddWithValue. See [Can we stop to use AddWithValue already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

While it has the advantage of the simplicity you couldn't trust it with precision because everything is inferred for you by your database engine that need to convert the received values to the expected structure of your database fields. (And I don't even start with the pitfalls caused by dates values passed as strings)

Even passing strings for text fields is not a good choiche because the parameter will have the same size of your string and this could interfere with the optimization technique employed by the database to parse your command

For example, [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx#duplicate=0), while focused on Sql Server, contains a lot of informations about the adverse effects that AddWithValue could cause to your database engine.

So just use the Add method like this. (Still one code line)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@myParam", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "myTextField").Value = "Test";
```

Comment: if i type it like that, i get a warning that its deprecated and that i should use AddWithValue. I red the article though but i'm  using quite common regular variable types, not custom types. So I should be fine width AddWithValue's. Maybe its because i'm using the current version of mySql and its connector.

Comment: No, you are reading [this overload of Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1(v=vs.110).aspx). The Add that takes only the parameter name and an object for the value is deprecated. And the reason is because when you pass an object there is a possible conflict with the overload that takes a DbType instead. There is no deprecation on the method explained above

Comment: not feeling so sure about this, i'd supose that database engines would implement this properly (or get fixed); as long as i dont put in types the connector isnt awaware off i shouldnt violate Addwidth value. As the types in use are pretty common ea Double Int long Decimal.